# Sync-ing ArcGIS Online and collector for ArcGIS?

Tags: arcmap, shapefile, arcgis-online, arcgis-collector

[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCgXl.jpg)I am new with "collector for ArcGIS" and we have just recieved the ArcGIS Online account to be able to provide data for Collector.
Based on the General instruction, we have shared some data ( Shape, Layerpacket,...)in Arcmap and were able to see them in ArcGIS online.

We shared them through our organization in ArcGIS online. Though the data editable is, still we can not see it in Collector.

I collector we have two Option either my Maps or all Maps and still non of them is visible.

What could be the Problem?

[image]

Comment: Looking at your my content I dont see a hosted feature layer under it. Is there an editable layer in the web map?

Answer (score 2):

Go to your Web Map in ArcGIS Online, then Settings - Web Map, check "Use in Collector for ArcGIS"

[image]

Comment: where do u mean exactly?

Comment: Sorry I am new ArcGIS Online....where can I see the Setting? is it possible u provide me with a screenshot?

Comment: I really appreciate your guidance. I am going to try it and let you know.

Comment: I have add screenshots of the view I have in ArcGIS Online. Soory that it is in German.  There is no Setting Option in the first view as yours but when I said share...there was a Setting Option on the top Right and after selecting that there was no Option for collector.

Comment: You have overlooked some setting. Have you tried ESRIs support?

Comment: You mean send request to ESRI Support?

Comment: Call them and talk to a person

Comment: Thank you I would do that. So in your opinion there is no other Option that I could do by myself

Comment: There are so many options that I cant remember all of them. Try following some ESRI guide to set up ArcGIS online and collector